# Glass looking shader when applying Fresnel

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I was trying to make a material by the method in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4

Everything is good except when I add the ***Fresnel*** to the ***Mix Shader*** node, I get what looks like a ***Glass*** shader around only one of the objects (the Bishop).  I have the same material on both objects:
[image: object with glass looking material]
[image: cycles material nodes]

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is that you're referring to.  Please provide additional information and screenshots to detail the exact issue you're having.

Comment: you cant see the pictur?

Comment: There is one picture and just from that it's very unclear what you're expecting and what you're seeing as a problem.  In order to help you, we need more information.  Just explain what the issue is.

Comment: the Bishop have the problem itsw seems like the uoutsaid of the matirial is glass somthing the Rook dosent have (them are the same matirial) i sorry i make it mor hard for you i just dontw know english well

Comment: [URL=https://www.fxp.co.il][IMG]https://i.imgur.com/3alo6ML.png[/IMG][/URL] [URL=https://www.fxp.co.il][IMG]https://i.imgur.com/VweEo8E.png[/IMG][/URL] the same problem are in more 2 models the king and the quiine

Comment: Select the Bishop, go into Edit Mode, select all vertices by pressing "A", and then press "Ctrl N".  That will ensure that all your Normals are facing the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your normals are probably facing the wrong way (inside). To correct this:

1.) Select the Bishop

2.) Go into ***Edit Mode***

3.) Select everything by pressing ***A***

4.) Press ***Ctrl*** + ***N*** to make the Bishop's ***Normals*** uniform.  Make sure not to check the *Inside* checkbox.  Observe:

[image]

[image]